# How do we properly flex an imbedded element both vertically and horizontally using flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have updated this issue with a simpler test case.  The sample below is the issue I have been stuck on.  If you run the HTML in a browser the screen will render as seen in the first screen shot below.  However, if you then manually go into web inspector and manually adjust the window-wrapper tag as follows:

flex-grow: 1;

the screen will render as desired - see second screen shot.  I do not understand why the the flex-grow tag is not being maintained in the window-wrapper tag on page load.  This happens in all browsers, so I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

screen shot broken

[image: page not rendered correctly]

screen shot fixed

[image: page rendered correctly]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<TITLE>TEST</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="TEXT/CSS">

body {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
html {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
html, body, .viewport {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#top_wrapper {
    height: 80px;
    min-width:885px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ff4422
}
#window_wrapper {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: .2em solid gray;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#page-head {
    width:730px;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-size:1.7em;
    color:black;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
}
#page {
    width:716px;
    min-height:280px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}
#title {
    width:500px;
}
#bottom-wrapper {
    height: 40px;
    min-width:885px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    background-color:#ff4422;
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="top_wrapper"></div>
<div id="window-wrapper">
    <div id="page-head">Page Title</div>
    <div id="page"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-wrapper"></div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Is [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/hj6eu03b/) what you want to achieve?

Comment: where is the code that you have tried?

Comment: It's strange, because the default is `align-self: stretch`.

Comment: Ricardo this is what we want.  Unfortunately our css is a bit more complicated and based on the nature of our code we cannot post the whole thing.  When we attempted your code, using 100vh - 200px calc, it pushed the content 3 box below the footer.  We will update the screen shot the best we can with our situation.  Is this something you could help us with offline, for which we would compensate you?

Comment: You don't have to post all your code or disclose any company secrets. You should post just enough code to reproduce the problem. This will (1) enable us to assist you effectively, (2) make this post useful to others as a quality reference source, and (3) adhere to Stack Overflow guidelines (minimizing the likelihood your question will be closed and/or downvoted).

Comment: Thank you Michael for the guidance.  We want to adhere to all guidelines.  It is a bit difficult for us to trim our code down to a minimum working example.  However, we are going to attempt to do so.

Comment: Because in your HTML the `id` is set to `window-wrapper`, and in the CSS you have `window_wrapper`. You're mixing underscores and dashes in your `class` and `id` names. Consider establishing a naming convention to  minimize these sorts of errors. I normally use dashes in HTML/CSS, and underscores in PHP. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Michael.  We had obviously been starring at things so long we grew blind.