# How can IE11 display discrepencies be isolated?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

My website's navigation structure works well in all browsers that I'm trying to support except IE11, which I definitely need to support so that users who have Windows 8.1 phones can use the responsive navigation. The responsive navigation is actually the only observable problem with IE11 compatibility; the layout active in desktop widths is fine in IE.

Trying to determine exactly what's different about the box model between IE11 and Chrome/Edge/Firefox has frustrated me because it seems that several CSS rules behave slightly differently. I assumed the issue was flexbox, but I also notice that IE11 doesn't handle margins the same way, as illustrated in this screenshot with IE11 shown beside Edge:

[image: Left browser is IE11. Right browser is Edge.]

The lack of space between the header and the off-white title heading's background-color in IE11 is due to a 40px margin-top on the `<main>` element not being rendered the same way. Nevertheless, that problem isn't directly related to the mobile menu's malfunctioning in IE11, as demonstrated in this picture:

[image: Left browser is IE11. Right browser is Edge. Mobile navigation expanded]

Though hard to see, the links in the expanded mobile navigation do still work in IE11, but the container not being rendered properly makes it practically unusable.

Here is the HTML structure for the mobile navigation:

```
<div id="mobile-nav_container">
    <div class="component-absolute-wrapper">
        <div id="mobile-nav_button" class="component-absolute mq-reveal js-toggle">
            <span>menu</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-nav_column-wrapper">
        <nav id="mobile-nav_column1">
            <!-- Elements are moved here by script when menu is expanded. -->
        </nav>
        <nav id="mobile-nav_column2">
            <!-- Elements are moved here by script when menu is expanded. -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's hard to simply show the CSS because many partials are compiled together and styles are modified by the script, but here are some relevant styles (in **Less**):

```
#mobile-nav_container {
    width: 100%;
}
#mobile-nav_column-wrapper {
    .mixin-blockcenter(90%); // The traditional "margin 0 auto" centering technique
}
#mobile-nav_button {
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#mobile-nav_column1, #mobile-nav_column2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin: 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    &> ul { // Child <ul> elements get added by the script on click
        .wrapper(50px);
    }
}
#mobile-nav_column1 {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#mobile-nav_column2 {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The problem is not only present when the menu is expanded. Here is a picture of the unexpanded menu (specifically the **mobile-nav_column-wrapper** element) highlighted in the inspectors on both IE11 and Edge on a version of the site that doesn't have the title heading (NOTE, in this picture Edge is on the left and IE is on the right):

[image: Left browser is Edge. Right browser is IE 11.]

I've been comparing the computed values of height, width, padding, etc. between the two browsers, but I don't see anything conclusive. I'm pretty sure it's not simply a flexbox issue, and in fact flexbox might even be working mostly the same in the expanded columns in IE11. What box model issue am I missing?

Comment: Having problems with IE of any version is normal and expected. Flexbox, in IE11, is riddled with bugs. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: I'm on Safari so I can't test. On quick glance, one of your div containers isn't closed properly. Also check [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3597276+ie11).

Comment: Also, you're just begging for trouble with all that back and forth between dashes and underscores. Eventually somebody handling your code will confuse them and [you'll come here looking for help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39216366/3597276) ;-)